# Force DOM replacement to trigger display animation

Tags: javascript, css, dom, reactjs

I have a component that looks like:

```
class Device extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let indicator = <i className="i display" />;
        if (this.props.n) {
            indicator = <i className="n display" />;
        }
        return <div>{indicators}</div>;
    }
}
```

Css:

```
.display {
    animation-name: appear;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
@keyframes appear {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

This all works great, and when the Device is initially rendered it does fade in.

The problem is that when the state changes to change the indicator from `i` to `n` (or vice versa) the DOM element does not get updated. I know this is on purpose because of React's virtual DOM but this actually prevents the `appear` animation from triggering again. I need the element to *reappear*.

Is there any way to get to trigger again on the class change?

Failing that is there any way to force React to replace the DOM element so `appear` is animated again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with the `key` attribute on React component elements. If the key is different, it signals to React that the element is different and should be re-rendered.  In this case, you can use the indicator value as part of the key to ensure it is different when it changes.

```
let indicator = <i key="i" className="i display" />;
if (this.props.n) {
    indicator = <i key="n" className="n display" />;
}
return <div>{indicators}</div>;
```